# IE11 and <a href> with div or img in Javascript/dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, internet-explorer-11

in my widgets html-template I have following a-tag:

```
<a class="mylink" href="" data-dojo-attach-point="downloadAttach"
                                dojoattachevent="onclick:_download">
<div class="mylinklayout"></div>
</a>
```

When clicked a file should be downloaded and the `href-attribute is set programmatically. This works fine in Chrome & Firefox, but not in IE11. The same happens wenn replacing the div-tag with a img-tag. All javascript code in the background will be executed as expected and only the download will not start (also IE11 does not prompt for saving/directly opening the file).

The download will only work when I'm not using div or img but only plain text within the a-tag (making a usual hyperlink):

```
<a class="mylink" href="" data-dojo-attach-point="downloadAttach"
                                dojoattachevent="onclick:_download">
download here
</a>
```

The javascript code remains unchanged and the href-attribute is set in the same way with the same value. Now it works in IE11.

Is there a work around for IE11 to get this working with div oder img?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem? Also have you done any debugging via the console?

Comment: I did some debugging via console... there are no errors and from there i know that the js-code works fine. The href is set properly. the problem is that only the a-tag is not working in IE11 (older versions like 9 do work).

For the jsfiddle: since the project is not a publicly accessible website... from there should I get a link for an Icon and from there should I get a download-link? I don't want to take something from somewhere in the Internet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why it works in older IE-Versions but not in IE11. This code snippet is made vor IE:

```
var scope = this;
setTimeout(function() { scope.close(); }, 500);
```

It seems that in IE the clickhandler shouldn't get processed immediately when iniating a download so this code was executed when IE got detected: the check for IE formerly was done with `dojo.isIe` and is now done with `sniff("ie")`. IE11 will not be detected with this check, one has to check for `trident`. Now the code snippet also will be executed for IE11 and everything works fine.